# can Elastic reformat JSON on ingest?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, influxdb

I have an IoT device that outputs data in this format:

```
{
    "host": "edison",
    "timestamp": 1560755080091,
    "fahrenheit": 72.824,
    "humidity": 51.746
}
```

I'm able to write this to an Elastic index (v 6.7.2) that I created with these mappings:

```
PUT temperature-humidity
{
  "mappings": {
    "temperature_humidity": {
      "properties": {
        "host": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "epoch_millis"
        },
        "fahrenheit": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "humidity": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also have an InfluxDB instance that expects the records to be formatted this like:

```
{
    "measurement": "temperature-humidity",
    "tags": {
        "host": "edison"
    },
    "fahrenheit": 72.824,
    "humidity": 51.746
}
```

If possible, I'd like to avoid having two different data formats.

If I tweaked the device to output data in the InfluxDB format, is there a way for Elastic to transform the data into the "flat" format as the records are ingested? Or do I need to do the transformation outside of Elastic?

Comment: This has to be done while ingesting the data. How do you ingest?

Comment: I'm using Kafka Connect to ingest the data. I could write a Kafka Streams job to munge the data - write the reformatted JSON to a new topic, and ingest that with Kafka Connect. That's easy peasy. My knowledge of Elastic isn't that great, and I was trying to minimize the number of components. I saw that there are scripted fields in Kibana, and wondered if it was possible to reformat inside Elastic using something like that.

Comment: You are on the right path then. Think of ES as just another db. When you insert the data you need to format as you want in advance. There are tools like logstash, filebeat etc that can do custom format ingestion but nothing on ES specifically to change the schema once a PUT request is received.

Comment: OK, perfect. Thanks, @TheUknown. I really just wanted to ensure that I'm not building something that's super hacky - where I could be embarrassed by someone asking "why didn't you just do that in Elastic?"

Comment: No, you're good. Atleast as of now, there's still nothing and i'm sure there wont be in future. In fact, if someone does this on ES side that'd be hacky because its a datastore, there shouldnt be any such logic in there.

Comment: Just in case, you don't want to set up another tools, please have a look on ingest pipelines in elasticsearch ingest nodes which allows you to transform incoming data to the desired structure in place.

Comment: Thanks, @ibexit. That's super interesting.

Comment: I second @ibexit here, definitely a job for [ingest processors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html)